# React - Why is geolocation state undefined when accessing it from another function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, geolocation

I'm trying to get the latitude and the longitude from geoLocation and use it to fetch data from a weather api. The problem however is that as soon as I pass latitude or longitude state into my fetchWeather function and try to access it, it only works once. If I reload the page the latitude and longitude state is shown as undefined, which is the initialstate. It is as if the state is not set again after page refresh. Outside the function the state works fine even after page reload.

```
function WeatherToday() {
  const [weather, setWeather] = useState([]);
  const [Loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const [latitude, setLatitude] = useState();
  const [longitude, setLongitude] = useState();

  const fethGeoLocation = async () => {
    try {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
        setLatitude(position.coords.latitude);
        setLongitude(position.coords.longitude);
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.warn(error);
    }
  };

  console.log(latitude, longitude);
  // Works on every call

  const fetchWeatherData = async () => {
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      console.log('geolocation', latitude, longitude);
      // does not work, latitude and longitude is undefined
      const res = await fetchWeather(latitude, longitude);
      setWeather(res.data);
      setLoading(false);
    } catch (error) {
      setLoading(false);
      console.warn(error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fethGeoLocation();
    fetchWeatherData();
  }, []);

  if (
    !Loading &&
    weather &&
  ) {
    return (
      <div className={WeatherTodayStyles.container}>
        <Forecast forecast={weather} />
        <HourlyForecast forecast={weather} />
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }
}

export default WeatherToday;
```

Comment: Because you have a stale closure. Both the function that sets the state and the function that attempts to use it are called on the same render. Those state values cannot be updated until the next render (a hint is that they are `consts` as well)

Comment: as @BrianThompson said state update is asynchronous, you can solve this by just fetching whether data directly inside `fethGeoLocation`

Comment: It's more than just being async though. Even if React had triggered the state update internally, there's no way for the `consts` to be reassigned during that render (it would throw an error). Technically it is async, but the observed problem is much more related to it being a stale closure.

Comment: Thank you for the answers and pointing me into the right direction. I don't know if solved it the best way but I researched a bit and solved it by using useRef